# how I can get the bottom of a element html

Tags: javascript

How I get the bottom of a element html for get the top ia offsettop and for get bottom how I do? any have know? I tryeid get height of element abs operate - any thing but what o can use how reference

Comment: `offsetTop + outerHeight`

Answer (score 0):

Use [`getBoundingClientRect()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) instead of [fiddling with offsets](http://ejohn.org/blog/getboundingclientrect-is-awesome/).

```
var position = element.getBoundingClientRect();
var bottom = position.top + position.height;
```